# On a 2004 Mitsubishi Lancer, Can a separated catalytic converter be re-attached to the exhaust manifold?

Tags: mitsubishi, catalytic-converter, exhaust-manifold

My question title pretty much covers it. This is a 2004 Lancer. The family car, not the sport version.

These pics might help:

[image: It ain't supposed to look like that!]
[image: Seperated!]

Can this be repaired without replacing the whole unit? (That's an apparently *cheap* aftermarket piece and it's out of warranty.)

Comment: Wow, that is a really cruddy looking exhaust manifold (flow characteristics really stink, I'd bet). You can most likely get this welded up without too much of an issue. As long as the cat isn't plugged and it's working, I'd do it. In fact I welded a friend's up which did kind of the same thing. I'm saying you can probably do this, but I'd highly suggest just getting a stock manifold and converter to replace. JMHO, so leaving it here as a comment.

Comment: I have a secondary question that might deserve it's own post, but I'll try it here. What are the consequences of driving it like this for a day, or maybe until the end of the week?

Comment: You cannot drive it like this. The oxygen sensor isn't adjusting for anything because it isn't in the exhaust stream. You run the real risk of exhaust in the passenger compartment. You really don't want to run it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be repaired with an aftermarket unit. The manifold has visible welds on it already, so it can be welded to. Almost any aftermarket catalytic converter should be weldable.

To perform this repair, a shop will have to remove the exhaust manifold from the car. Almost any exhaust & muffler shop should be capable of performing this repair. However, they will need to include a provision for installing the oxygen sensor before the catalytic converter. Otherwise your car will not run correctly.

Comment: I tried JB Weld "High Heat" and bailing wire. :-) It was a complete failure. I had a guy weld it in place and it seems to be doing just fine. Thanks for the suggestion. (Probably would have been better to disassemble / reassemble, but for what little I paid, I'm sure it's "Good Enough".)